# Faking browser location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I'm automating tests for web app using Selenium. This web app uses current location information from browser using HTML5 Geolocation API. In my tests I want my browser to provide fake location to the application. Is there anything I can do fake my browser location using javascript? Like overriding complete HTML5 Geolocation API?

Comment: for an xbrowser solution, write a simple wrapper function around the native method and call it from your code instead. clobber that function with a mock, or do an if(testing) fork in the wrapper when you need to test.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use certain add-ons for Firefox (Geolocator) and Chrome (Manual GeoLocator) which you can use to override the location information provided by the Geolocation API. These work for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome, with its developer tools, lets you simulate many things if [you check the Emulatioon checkbox](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#enable-emulation-panel), among them the location of the browser.

[image]

See [related Chrome documentation](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#device-geolocation-overrides)